# asp.net mvc get absolute url (behind proxy)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
user --> internet --> server1 (iis proxy) --> server2 (hosting the website)
```

I'm trying to get the absolute url.

The code below has worked without any problem when we were not using a proxy:

```
string fullUrl = Url.Action("Bar", "Foo", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = pid, search = search }), Request.Url.Scheme);
string fullUrlEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fullUrl);
```

However now instead I receive this absolute url with internal ip:

```
 http://192.168.0.3/Foo/Bar/5
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do, actually. The application won't have visibility into the reverse proxy utilizing it. If you absolutely need the absolute URL, you'll likely have to simply hardcode it in something like Application Settings. Then you can create a UrlHelper extension to read that value and construct a true absolute URL based on that.

Comment: The benefit to Application Settings is that you can alter the value via config transforms.

Comment: You might investigate whether the proxy is setting the X-Forwarded-For header. If not, configuring it to do so might produce a more desirable result.

Comment: Mark, I don't receive these header info, so can't use it. Also I've read that it is vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by hardcoding the url in the appsettings and adding it to the url as suggested by Chris Pratt.
I could not use any X-Forwarded-For header, it was enabled but I didn't receive that information, so could not use it.